# python map reduce Words with exact same vowels

Tags: python, mapreduce

I am trying to find and count words with the same vowel combinations. The vowels on each line are in alphabetical order, followed by a colon, then followed by the number of words that contained exactly those vowels. If there are words with no vowels, nothing is printed before the colon. So my output from the mapper is this:

[image: input file]

and my output should look like this - :2  eo:2 eeo:1 eoo: 1 but instead I get eo 2 eoo 2. So I am missing the spaces and the eeo. Here is my code:

```
    import sys
     

    current_key_being_processed = None
    next_key_found = None
    vowel_total = 0
    vowel_dict = {}

    for line in sys.stdin:

      next_key_found, value = line.split('\t')
      next_key_found = sorted(next_key_found)
      next_key_found = ''.join(next_key_found)
      if current_key_being_processed == next_key_found:
              vowel_total = vowel_total + int(1)  
      
      if current_key_being_processed != next_key_found:
           vowel_total = 0   
           if next_key_found is not None:
                 current_key_being_processed = next_key_found
                 vowel_total = vowel_total + int(1)                           
                  
      else:
      
            
           if current_key_being_processed:
               current_key_being_processed = ''.join(sorted(current_key_being_processed))         
               vowel_dict[current_key_being_processed] = vowel_total
               vowel_total = 0 
               current_key_being_processed = next_key_found

    if current_key_being_processed == next_key_found:
          vowel_total = vowel_total + int(1)    
          vowel_dict[current_key_being_processed] = vowel_total    
            

    for key in sorted(vowel_dict.keys()): 
        print('final dict =',key, vowel_dict[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am following correctly. Is this what you are looking for?

```
words  = ['   1','   1','eoe 1','oe  1','oe  1','ooe 1']
vowels = {}
for word in words:
    key         = ''.join(sorted(c for c in word.strip(' 1') if c in 'aeiouy'))
    vowels[key] = vowels.get(key,0) + 1
print(vowels)
```

Comment: I already have vowel combinations as an input from my mapper so it would be something like:            ae 1  ea 1   eoo 1 ooe 1                                                                                                                                   so my output would be ae 2 eoo 2                                                                                     so I have to count the vowel combinations

Comment: I updated with your sequence from above, is that not what you were looking for?

Comment: Looks like our comments crossed - see my comments just above yours. My input is vowel combinations and the number one. I need to find all combinations with the exact same vowels and add up the number of occurrences.

Comment: Will that work for any vowel combo I have coming in?

Comment: I will try that thsnks.